# Update PHP File via Wordpress Theme Editor Fails

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm unable to update PHP code via the WordPress theme editor anymore. When I try to change the functions.php of my child theme with just adding a comment it fails with the following message:

> Unable to communicate back with the site to check for fatal errors, so the PHP change was reverted. You will need to upload your PHP file change by some other means, such as by using SFTP.

I have no idea where to start - can I access a more precise error message somewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Kindly check the permissions of the theme folder, WordPress site must not be able to write the changes in the file. That is why this error is coming.

Hope this helps